# Cannot set property 'onclick' of undefined when working across two files

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, canvas

In a file `Grid.ts` I have the following functions:

```
    get canvas(): HTMLCanvasElement {
        return this._canvas;
    }

    public revive( cell: Cell ) {
        this.cells.push(cell);
    }

    public kill( cell: Cell ) {
        this._cells.splice(this._cells.indexOf(cell));
    }

    public isAlive( cell: Cell ) {
        return this._cells.filter(c => c.asKey() == cell.asKey()).length > 0;
    }
```

I want to be able to click and kill / revive certain blocks of my grid on canvas to be filled or unfilled. So in my `main.ts` file I added:

```
grid.canvas.onclick = (function(e) {

//mouseclick position
let mx = e.offsetX;
let my = e.offsetY;

//calculate grid square numbers rounded to the nearest 10
let gx = Math.round(mx / CELL_SIZE) *10;
let gy = Math.round(my / CELL_SIZE) *10;

//if pressed before, kill it
if(grid.isAlive(Cell.of(gx, gy))) {
    grid.kill(Cell.of(gx, gy));

//else revive or bring to life
} else {
    grid.revive(Cell.of(gx, gy));
}
```

});

When running this, before even attempting to click the screen I get:

```
    Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of undefined
```

right on the line where I am calling `grid.canvas.onclick = (function() {...`

Why is it that `grid.canvas` is undefined and what can I do to fix this?

Comment: How are you defining `grid`? Also, save yourself and others the pain of readability and just use `Math.floor` instead of the double `~~` `NOT` bitwise shift. It's actually not an alias, as there is a slight difference in what it does.

Comment: can you share your whole Grid.ts file? and possibly your HTML?

Comment: @SterlingArcher grid is defined in my `main.ts` as `const grid: Grid = new Grid(MAX_CELLS, CELL_SIZE);`

Comment: @RobbieMilejczak I added all the functions I spoke on in the Grid.ts file. And I am no longer using the html `getElemenetById`. Canvas is as simple as `<canvas ></canvas >` in my html file.

Comment: When you're instantiating your Grid class, where are you passing in the canvas? How are you getting a hold of the canvas element? We can't tell why your canvas field is undefined if we don't know how it's assigned in the first place.